# Read text file and copy specific text in different order into new text file using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Hoping for help with a very specific problem. I'm new to batch programming and want to archive the following using a batch file.

Read all lines of a textfile1 and put values in different order into textfile2 with header line.

Example: textfile1 (input file)
From this file I want to read line by line and pick just certain content. The structure is kind of label="Value"spacelabel"Value"space and so on for each line (trying to demonstrate below):

```
Supplier CountryName="GB" SupplierNumber="1112|DISCOUNT|497" Street="ANDERTON HOUSE" CountryCoded="GB" Name1="ANDERTON BOARD AND PACKAGING" CorporateGroupID="497"
Supplier CountryName="GB" SupplierNumber="113093|AMB HEAD OFFICE|846" Street="Langcliffe Paper Mills" CountryCoded="GB" Name1="JOHN ROBERTS HOLDINGS LTD" CorporateGroupID="846"
```

Example: textfile2 (output file)
The first line should be a header line for which each label is separated by TAB and underneath I want to write the values found in textfile1 for each field.
If there is no value for a field then I want to add a TAB instead before adding the new found value.
As you can see I only want to pick the values between the quotation marks and nothing else.
The structure of textfile1 is always the same (order does not change) and the labels as well. Each line always starts with Supplier CountryName=
Just wondering if this is possible using a batch file.

```
SupplierNumber  Location    CorporateGroupID    Name1   Name2   Description POBox   CountryCoded
1112|DISCOUNT|497       497 ANDERTON BOARD AND PACKAGING            GB
113093|AMB HEAD OFFICE|846      846 JOHN ROBERTS HOLDINGS LTD               GB
```

Any input on this would be mighty helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65822358.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

:: Special characters
:: the variable TAB should be set to a tab character. This may not be copy/pastable from SO code to editors. 
:: Make sure that this is a single TAB as intended, not a space-sequence
SET "tab=   "

SET "columnsrequired=SupplierNumber Location CorporateGroupID Name1 Name2 Description POBox CountryCoded"


SET "header="
FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO SET "%%c="&SET "header=!header!%tab%%%c"

(
ECHO %header:~1%
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO SET "%%c="
 SET "lineread=%%b"
 FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO (SET "%%c=!lineread:*%%c=!")
rem FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO ECHO %%c is '!%%c!'
 rem each variable now contains either the full original line or '="required value" waffle...`
 FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO (
  SET "lineread=!%%c!"
  IF "!lineread:~0,1!"=="=" (
  rem change " to \ as " is a special character in batch
  SET "lineread=!lineread:"=\!"
rem  ECHO lineread "!lineread!"
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=\" %%x IN ("!lineread!") DO SET "%%c=%%x"
  ) ELSE (SET "%%c=")
 )
 SET "header="
 FOR %%c IN (%columnsrequired%) DO SET "header=!header!%tab%!%%c!"
 ECHO !header:~1!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: You are a camp! Thank you so much for your respons. This was exactly what I was after. You totally made my day, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your "question" is just a code request, that are usually deleted on this forum... However, I have some spare time, so here it is the solution you requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define output fields
set "fields=SupplierNumber Location CorporateGroupID Name1 Name2 Description POBox CountryCoded"

rem Get TAB character
for /F "delims=pR tokens=1,2" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set "TAB=%%b"

rem Assemble Header and Output "format" lines, and initialize fields
set "header="
set "output="
for %%a in (%fields%) do (
   set "header=!header!%%a!TAB!"
   set "output=!output!^!%%a:~1,-1^!!TAB!"
   set "%%a="
)

rem Process the file
(
echo %header:~0,-1%
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (textfile1.txt) do (
   call :GetFields %%b
   echo %output:~0,-1%
)) > textfile2.txt
goto :EOF


:GetFields
set line=%*
set %line:" ="&set %
exit /B
```

**textfile1.txt**:

```
Supplier CountryName="GB" SupplierNumber="1112|DISCOUNT|497" Street="ANDERTON HOUSE" CountryCoded="GB" Name1="ANDERTON BOARD AND PACKAGING" CorporateGroupID="497"
Supplier CountryName="GB" SupplierNumber="113093|AMB HEAD OFFICE|846" Street="Langcliffe Paper Mills" CountryCoded="GB" Name1="JOHN ROBERTS HOLDINGS LTD" CorporateGroupID="846"
```

**textfile2.txt**:

```
SupplierNumber    Location    CorporateGroupID    Name1    Name2    Description    POBox    CountryCoded   
1112|DISCOUNT|497          497    ANDERTON BOARD AND PACKAGING                      GB   
113093|AMB HEAD OFFICE|846          846    JOHN ROBERTS HOLDINGS LTD                      GB
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer to my "question". So very greatful you could help me. Very much appriciate you spending some time on this.Cheers.